# Why can't I assign array to pandas DataFrame column?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am using `KNeighborsClassifier` to classify some values like this:

```
arr = classifier_3NN.predict(testData_df)
len(arr)
10960
```

I want to assign this array to a column in a DataFrame, I have checked & it is the same size:

```
len(df[df['events']=='NaN']['events'])
10960
```

> When I do the following command the array values are not in the column as expected:

```
df[df['events']=='NaN']['events'] = arr
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) for checking `NaN` values with [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
df.ix[df['events'].isnull(), 'events'] = arr
```

But if need replace `NaN` values by `arr` better is use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by `Series` created from `arr`:

```
arr = [5,7,9]

df = pd.DataFrame({'events':[np.nan, 1, np.nan]})
print (df)
   events
0     NaN
1     1.0
2     NaN

df['events'] = df['events'].fillna(pd.Series(arr, index=df.index))
print (df)
   events
0     5.0
1     1.0
2     9.0
```

Comment: So do you need replace `NaN` values in `df['events']` by `arr`?